# Funcionamiento no deseado react memo

Tags: reactjs

Tengo un codigo similar a esto:

```
const Title = memo(
  ({ title, style }) => {
    console.log("render");
    return <div style={style}>{title}</div>;
  },
  (p, pv) => {
    return true;
  }
);

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      {state}
      <button onClick={() => setState(state + 1)}>Add</button>
      <Title style={{ color: "red" }} title={"Mark"} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

La teoría es que con `memo`, si la `prop` no cambia, no debe de volver a renderizarse.

Si observamos la consola, cada vez que le damos al boton ADD, se vuelve a renderizar el componente en el que usamos `memo`. [Aqui un ejemplo en codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mutable-sun-lgyry).

Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: La proxima, intenta agregando el codigo relevante a la pregunta porque puede que en un futuro el link deje de funcionar.

Comment: Anotado, muchas gracias de nuevo @Einer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El hook [`memo(component, areEqual)`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) recibe 2 funciones como parametros, no 1. Y en el segundo parametro es donde indicas si las propiedad son iguales, entonces no hace la re-rendirizacion, de lo contrario realiza la re-rendirizacion.

Aqui el componente `Title` actualizado:

```
// por defecto returnamos true para que no re-renderize
const esIgual = (prevProps, nextProps) => { return true; }

const Title = memo(
  ({ title, style }) => {
    console.log("render");
    return <div style={style}>{title}</div>;
  }, 
  this.esIgual // parametro isEqual para verificar si re-renderizar el componente
);
```

Y esto es una nota desde la doc oficional sobre el parametro metodo `isEquals` del hook `memo`:

> A diferencia del método `shouldComponentUpdate()` en los componentes de
>   la clase, la función `areEqual` devuelve `true` si los `props` son
>   iguales y `falso` si los `props` no son iguales. Este es el inverso
>   de `shouldComponentUpdate`.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!!!